# Prove that a sequence diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $b > 1$. Prove that the sequence $\frac{b^n}{n}$ diverges to $\infty$

I know that I need to show that $\dfrac{b^n}{n} \geq M $, possibly by solving for $n$, but I am not sure how.

If I multiply  both sides by $n$, you get  $b^n \geq Mn$, but I don't know if that is helpful.

Comment: try taking logarithms with base $b$ to $b^{n} \geq Mn$. How does the growth of $n$ compare to that of $\log_{b}n$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $b>1$, we can write $b=1+a$, where $a>0$. From binomial theorem, we then have
$$b^n = (1+a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}k a^k > \dbinom{n}2 a^2$$
Hence, we get that
$$\dfrac{b^n}n > \dfrac{(n-1)a^2}2$$
I trust you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use L'Hospital's rule:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b^n}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b^n\log{b}}{1}=\infty
$$